# How to make value of for loop to get sent back into the loop

Tags: matlab

Well I have been trying this problem for over 10 hours and have no idea how to do this problem, here it is:

> Imagine that you are a proud new parent. You decide to start a college
>   savings plan for your child, hoping to have enough in 18 years.
>   Suppose that your folks give you $1000 to get started and that each
>   month you can contribute $100. Suppose also that the interest rate is
>   6% per year compounded monthly, which is equivalent to 0.5% each
>   month. Because of interest payments and your contribution, each month
>   your balance will increase in accordance with the formula:
>
> ```
> New Balance = Old Balance + interest + your contribution
> ```
>
> Use a for loop to find the amount in the savings account each month
>   for the next 18 years. (Create a vector of values.) Plot the amount in
>   the account as a function of time.

The part that I am stuck on is how to make the new balance get plugged back into the equation 216 times (for 18 years).  I am able to get the first monthly balance but don't know how to make the loop continue for the remaining 215 months.
Any tips? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you mean something like this:

```matlab
iterations = 12*18;
old_bal = 1000;
monthly = 100;
balance = zeros(iterations,1);
for i=1:iterations
    balance(i) = old_bal;
    interest = old_bal*0.5/100;
    new_bal = old_bal + interest + monthly;
    old_bal = new_bal;
end

plot(1:iterations,balance)
```

Comment: omg wow yes that makes sense lol you have no idea how happy i am right now! thank you so much!! i can actually get some sleep tonight lol

Answer (score 2):

Forget about old and new. The basic idea is this:

```
Balance = 0;

for j=1:216,
    Balance = Balance + interest + your contribution;
end
```